# strtok function of C definition

Tags: c, function

The following is an example of the function strok from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok

Does anyone know why

```
pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
```

is used instead of

```
pch = NULL;
```

?

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Refer the doc : http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok

Comment: or this http://cyberspock.com/2015/08/18/here-be-strtok/

Comment: Have you looked how `strtok` works? means why you pass it NULL as an argument ?

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `NULL` as the first argument to `strtok()`, it's an indication that you want to carry on with the current tokenising operation (i.e., get the next matching token). It maintains certain state information between calls which makes this possible.

It *looks* like you may be thinking that:

```
pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
```

will tokenise the `NULL` string but that's not actually how it works. The `strtok()` function uses that argument to decide whether you're starting a *new* tokenising operation (non-`NULL`) or continuing with the *current* one (`NULL`).

That's *totally* different to setting the pointer to `NULL`. Doing so would only get the first token from that string rather than all of them.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok()` maintains an internal reference to the last thing it parsed. Calling `strtok(NULL, " ,.-")` keeps parsing the unparsed remainder of the string. Checking if the return value is `NULL` (as stored in `pch`) tells you when there is no more string left to parse. Setting `pch` to `NULL` explicitly would end the loop after a single iteration since parsing the first `n-1` tokens will return a non-`NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

The first call in `strtok()` must have a string, which it will parse to get the first token string. The `strok()` will maintain the remainder of the unparsed string internally. So, setting `NULL` in the first argument of `strtok()` is used to indicate that carry on with the current string. In case a new string is provided, `strtok()` will remove the unparsed string and will go forward with the new string.

Setting `NULL` to pch and then calling `strtok()` will not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In your reference link:

> *On a first call*, the function expects a C string as argument for **str**,
>   whose first character is used as the starting location to scan for
>   tokens. *In subsequent calls*, the **function expects a null pointer** and
>   uses the position right after the end of the last token as the new
>   starting location for scanning.

Also note that `pch` is **the token** itself returned by the `strtok`.

*Note: Read the answer paying attention to the highlights.*